# I made the html & js code to do the validation check. But the data is submitted before checking the data

Tags: html, spring, validation

```
<form name="mForm" action="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/login/insertSeller.do" method="post">

id : <input type="text" name="id" />

<input type="submit" value="register" onClick="doAction()" />

</form>

<script>

function doAction() {

var f = document.mForm;
        var id = f.id;

if (id.value == "") {
            alert("insert your id");
            id.focus();
            return false;
        }
 return true;
  }


</script>
```

Is there any error to correct?

If I click the button, the alert window opens with a message,

but the data is submitted without the validation check.

What do I need to do?

Please help me :)

Comment: Maybe search on google ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You really shouldn’t have inline event handlers in modern HTML. Nevertheless, you could try the following:

```
<input … onclick="return doAction()">
```

The `return` in the `onclick` causes the `input` to wait for permission.

For the sake of completeness, here is how I would do it in a modern browser:

First, use a `button` instead:

```
<button type="submit">register</button>
```

Second, give your button a name

```
<button name="register" type="submit">register</button>
```

You can give a name to the older style `input` element, and the process will still work.

Next, add the following to your JavaScript:

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded',function() {
    document.querySelector('button[name="register"]).onclick=doAction;
},false);
```

The main function acts as a startup script. The point of it is that it is waiting for the DOM to have loaded. Otherwise it’s not possible to look for elements that aren’t there yet.

Note that you assign to the `onclick` event handler the *name* of the function.

Comment: Thank you so much. because of your help, I solved the problem. And I have a question. Instead of the inline event handlers, do I need to use <button> tag?

Comment: @stick Using `button` is a separate matter, but it is recommended anyway. I have amended the answer to include the preferred method. If it’s satisfactory, you might accept the answer.

Comment: @stick You’re welcome. Do you want to accept the answer (ticking on it)?

Comment: oh sorry, I checked the check mark, and it turned green. is it the right way to accept the answer?